# Get Data Object From Array On Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have data retrieved from the API in the following form

```
[
    {
        "end_date": 1640908800000,
        "rev": 151,
        "usage_limit": 0,
        "reason_deleted": null,
        "picture_detail": "test",
        "revtype": 0,
        "linked_type": "SPECIFIC",
        "modified_date": 1644893309181,
        "type": "OPEN",
        "created_by": "januardy.hp@gmail.com",
        "is_multiple": null,
        "campaign_name": "Blewah 2022",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_auto_apply": true,
        "modified_by": "januardy.hp@gmail.com",
        "campaign_code": "BLEWAH2",
        "id": 76,
        "created_date": 1644893309181,
        "picture_banner": "test",
        "remarks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
        "start_date": 1609459200000,
        "status": "APPROVED"
    },
    {
        "end_date": 1644969600000,
        "rev": 152,
        "usage_limit": 0,
        "reason_deleted": null,
        "picture_detail": "",
        "revtype": 0,
        "linked_type": "SPECIFIC",
        "modified_date": 1644900601884,
        "type": "OPEN",
        "created_by": "januardy.hp@gmail.com",
        "is_multiple": null,
        "campaign_name": "BLEWAH 4",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_auto_apply": false,
        "modified_by": "januardy.hp@gmail.com",
        "campaign_code": "BLEWAH",
        "id": 78,
        "created_date": 1644900601884,
        "picture_banner": "",
        "remarks": "",
        "start_date": 1644883200000,
        "status": "APPROVED"
    },
    {
        "end_date": 1644969600000,
        "rev": 153,
        "usage_limit": 0,
        "reason_deleted": null,
        "picture_detail": "",
        "revtype": 1,
        "linked_type": "SPECIFIC",
        "modified_date": 1644900601884,
        "type": "OPEN",
        "created_by": "januardy.hp@gmail.com",
        "is_multiple": null,
        "campaign_name": "BLEWAH 4",
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_auto_apply": false,
        "modified_by": "januardy.hp@gmail.com",
        "campaign_code": "BLEWAH",
        "id": 78,
        "created_date": 1644900601884,
        "picture_banner": "",
        "remarks": "",
        "start_date": 1644883200000,
        "status": "APPROVED"
    },
]
```

Now I need to get the data inside that array, and display it on table on Angular 11 using Typescript, either it's the key, like `"start_date"`, and the value of the key, like "status": `"APPROVED"`. I already try to use Object.value and Object.key, but the return is like this

[image: The result of my work for now]

I got the key, but the value just like [Object]. I need to get the value and display it on table using Angular Material Table. Can someone help me please?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post your relevant ts and html code.

Comment: Try using `ngFor`. If you want to use Object.key add html code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If building a table display, you can also make an array of headers, push keys from the first element and in template display the headers and loop through items in your json and display them. Like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-key-value-table-qnctbf

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me 

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of item | keyvalue">
    <td> prop.key </td>
    <td> prop.value </td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```